# Using Visual Studio to build an HTA (or single-page local HTML file application) with TypeScript

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript, hta

I have a rather large HTA that I still need to maintain. I originally wrote it using Notepad++, but because of its growth I am now interested in the Intellisense capabilities offered by TypeScript. It would also be helpful to have Visual Studio's HTML and CSS development tools.

I am aware that I'll have to add type annotations to the application, but it is still worth my while, and can be done gradually.

Using the **File -> New Project -> HTML Application with TypeScript** outputs a DLL for use with IIS Express or another web server. The output I need is the HTML, CSS and TypeScript compiled to Javascript with references adjusted in the HTML.

In short, I need the following:

1. Output HTML/CSS files instead of a DLL (The extension should be renamed to **.hta** but I can do that in a post-build step.
2. Output TypeScript files as Javascript
3. Intellisense for all TypeScript/Javascript files included in the project
4. Optionally, allow adding Javascript/TypeScript libraries via Nuget (I can add them by hand, but I would prefer not to).
5. Optionally, Visual Studio debugging (Using the `debugger` keyword in Javascript allows me to start a debugging session with Visual Studio, once the HTA is started using the `mshta.exe` executable. However, it would be nice to set breakpoints in the editor window without modifying the code.)

How can I use Visual Studio (2013 Professional) for this scenario?

NB. I have extensive experience using Visual Studio for desktop applications (C#/VB.NET and WPF) but I have no experience in Web development. I have a fair knowledge of HTML, CSS and Javascript in the HTA environment.

---

**Update**

I tried creating a new web site (**File -> New Web Site ...**) but I cannot add TypeScript files to the site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I created a new "HTML Application with TypeScript" project. That gives me points 1-4.

I renamed "index.html" to "index.hta" in the solution -- no need to do this in post-build. Visual Studio recognizes the .hta extension as an HTML file.

I set the build properties to open `mshta.exe` as an external program, with the full path of the HTA as a command-line argument. I haven't been able to attach the current Visual Studio window to the HTA process (so no breakpoints), but the `debugger` statement opens a JIT debugging dialog box and prompts to open a new Visual Studio session, with full debugging capabilities.

An unexpected bonus is that I can debug the TypeScript file, and I am not limited to debugging the generated Javascript.

**Update**

Currently, I would prefer to use Visual Studio Code for HTA development; VS Code was not available at the time that I answered this. For this task, Visual Studio offers no benefits over VS Code.

Comment: @DusanJovanovic You just have to set the `.hta` file extension as handled by the HTML editor, and wrap the `<HTA:APPLICATION` in a conditional comment. I use TypeScript to write the code and reference the transpiled Javascript from the HTA. Same for CSS. There are TypeScript definitions for some ActiveX object models (like [Excel](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/activex-excel), [Word](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/activex-word),  ...

Comment: ... [ADODB](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/activex-adodb) and [Scripting Runtime](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/activex-scripting) among others). I've been meaning to test if VS Code can attach to a process and debug a script, but in the meantime I use Visual Studio 2017 for debugging; it handles the mapping from TypeScript to Javascript. What has your experience been like?

Comment: @DusanJovanovic I also have been meaning to try configuring a run task for VS Code.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. VS2017 only for me. Have not tried TypeScript yet.  But the problem is mshta.exe on Win10. For some hta's it just "magically" stops ... It uses IE engine and one never knows which modern css or html or javascript will make it misbehave...

Comment: Right now fFor some reason I can not add "Zev Spitz" with a at sign in the front, in the comments?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163845/discussion-between-zev-spitz-and-dusan-jovanovic).

Comment: On Windows 10, HTAs are run in IE8 mode. But if you add `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=11">`, then you get IE11 mode. The only restriction I found is that embedded VBScript won't run, only JScript. But this should not be a problem, since you are using TypeScript anyway.

Comment: @kol Using the `meta` tag indeed runs under IE11 mode, but all the [HTA-specific settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536495(v=vs.85).aspx) are ignored.

Answer (score 2):

VS 2013 works very well. There are Grunt/Gulp task runners,  some made by MS, others made by third parties, for VS 2013.

Use Grunt or Gulp as part of your build process. You can start Grunt and Gulp as a build task. Either task runner should be used to minify, concatenate and version js,  and styles. It can even be used to compile Typescript, though msbuild does a good job with that.

Ignore the dll made by Msbuild. Don't deploy it. The team I am working on is building an spa application on vs2013 with typescript that gets double and deployed to Linux/Apache as a two minimified js files, one css file, some image and font assets, and a index.html file.

Comment: Thanks for prompting me to dive into Grunt, but I don't need it in the end.